# Why is $\sqrt{x/x^{-1}}$ OR $\sqrt{x/{1/x}}$ = $\lvert x\rvert$ and not just x

Tags: exponentiation, radicals, absolute-value

I have this task:
Find equal expression to square root of fraction of x and its inverted value (this is translated from my mother tongue so I'm sorry if I've used incorrect terms). Anyway the starting point is clear reduce this:

$\sqrt{\frac{x}{x^{-1}}}$

The correct answer is $\lvert x\rvert$ and I don't know how to get there. It seems I am missing some correct thinking at the very last step.

So this is what I do (even the slightest mindsteps included):

$\sqrt{\frac{x}{x^{-1}}} = \sqrt{\frac{x}{\frac{1}{x}}} = 
\sqrt{\frac{\frac{x}{1}}{\frac{1}{x}}} = 
\frac{\sqrt{\frac{x}{1}}}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}} =
\frac{\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{1}}}{\frac{\sqrt{1}}{\sqrt{x}}} =
\frac{\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}} =
{\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1}}\cdot{\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1}} = \sqrt{x}\cdot\sqrt{x} = (\sqrt{x})^2
$ which I believe $=x$

OR

$\sqrt{\frac{x}{x^{-1}}} = 
\sqrt{\frac{x}{\frac{1}{x}}} = 
\sqrt{\frac{\frac{x}{1}}{\frac{1}{x}}} = 
\frac{\sqrt{\frac{x}{1}}}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}} =
\frac{\frac{x^\frac{1}{2}}{1}}{\frac{1}{x^\frac{1}{2}}} =
{\frac{x^\frac{1}{2}}{1}}\cdot{\frac{x^\frac{1}{2}}{1}} = 
x^\frac{1}{2}\cdot x^\frac{1}{2} =
x^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}} =
x^1 = 
x
$

If this is correct then how $(\sqrt{x})^2 \neq x$ and instead$(\sqrt{x})^2 =\lvert x\rvert$ ?

EDIT: so the answer is that this split 
$\sqrt{\frac{\frac{x}{1}}{\frac{1}{x}}} = \frac{\sqrt{\frac{x}{1}}}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}}$ is forbidden since it is valid for positive x only. And x is unknown. What I should have done is this less fancy but correct $\sqrt{\frac{\frac{x}{1}}{\frac{1}{x}}} = \sqrt{{\frac{x}{1}}\cdot{\frac{x}{1}}} =
\sqrt{{x}\cdot{x}} = \sqrt{x^2}$ which indeed is $\lvert x\rvert$

Comment: You have to be careful when "splitting" $\sqrt{x\cdot x}$ into $\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x}$ since the latter is only well defined for $x\geq 0$ (and in this case $x=|x|$)

Comment: $\sqrt {w/v}=\sqrt {w}/\sqrt {v} $ **ONLY** if you know w and v are positive. You don't know this so you can't say this.  But you do know.  $\sqrt {x/(1/x)}=\sqrt {x^2}$.  And $\sqrt {x^2}=|x|$.  If x < 0 then |x| is not x.

Comment: Go through this with x = -4 and see what happens.

Comment: Oh! Now I get it @fleablood. Forbidden operation. Thanks.

Comment: Not so much forbidden as mistaken assumptions.  If x is positive, root (x)^2 = root (x^2)=x.  no harm no foul.  If x is negative root (x^2) = -x = (if root (-1)=i is allowed) root (x)^2.  But need to realize neg value of x is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$ because the square root is always positive. So if $x < 0$ then $\sqrt{x^2} = -x$ (for example $\sqrt{(-2)^2} = \sqrt{4} = 2 = -(-2)$), i.e.
$$
\sqrt{x^2} = 
\begin{cases}
x, & x \ge 0 \\
-x, & x < 0
\end{cases}
$$
which is exactly definition of $|x|$.

In your case $\sqrt{x/x^{-1}} = \sqrt{x/(1/x)} = \sqrt{x^2} = |x|$.

Comment: I lived with the impression that there is great difference between
$(\sqrt{x})^2$
and 
$\sqrt{x^2}$

while the latter turns any x to positive, the former is undefined for negative x. And $\sqrt{x}\cdot\sqrt{x} = (\sqrt{x})^2$ not $\sqrt{x^2}$
Am I mistaken here?

Comment: Yes, you are right - $\sqrt{x^2}$ and $(\sqrt{x})^2$ are not the same functions because first one is defined for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and the second one is defined only for $x\ge 0$. Moreover, if we consider $\sqrt{x}$ as $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ function, it will be also defined for negative $x$ as $\sqrt{x} = i\sqrt{-x}$ where $i$ is imaginary unit. And then $(\sqrt{x})^2 = x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, which is still not the same to $|x| = \sqrt{x^2}$.

Comment: with the help of you and fleablood I realized where I made the mistake. Thanks

Comment: For pos x, root (x squared) = root (x squared = x but if x is neg root x is undefined and x squared is positive but root (x squared) is also pos so =|x|.  Just have to be careful.  If complex numbers are allowed then root (-1) =i  is acceptable but the "splittin" doesn't work.  For x <0 root (x) = i root (|x|) But root (ab) needn't equal root(a)root (b).  It does in absolute value terms but the signs might have different results.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you can do these properties only if they  $(a,b)$ are positive.

> $$\sqrt { \frac { a }{ b }  } =\frac { \sqrt { a }  }{ \sqrt { b }  } ,\quad \sqrt { ab } =\sqrt { a } \sqrt { b } $$

Answer (score 0):

Functions are usually defined to have only one "out-value". Sometimes when defining a function (for example for the purpose of expressing the solutions of an equation) one has to pick a **branch**. This basically means to pick one of the solutions to the equation as out-value for the function.

For example the equation

$$x^2 = k$$

When solving this equation, we write $$x = \pm \sqrt{k}$$

Where $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is usually defined to be a branch so that is the positive value which squared equals $k$.

If we choose that branch, then $\sqrt{.}$ will always be positive.